# Gameobjects disappearing when changing renderer.material.color

Tags: rendering, unity, procedural-generation, color, materials

I'm generating an array of objects using this code:

```
    while(currentPosition.z < poolSize){
        var ringObj = GameObject.Instantiate(ring) as GameObject;          
        ringObj.transform.position = currentPosition;
        ringObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color =  new Color (1.0f, 0f, 0f);
        // Adds the ring to the pool.
        pool[(int)currentPosition.z] = ringObj;
        updateCurrentPosition ();
    }
```

This works fine without this line:

```
ringObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color =  new Color(Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f));
```

Which should randomize the color of the object. The problem is that instead of doing this, the whole code would generate only one object (I can see it on the hierarchy view) with the standard material color and then stops the generation.
Also, the material is not changing color.

I can't understand why this happens. Can someone explain this to me, please?  I'm using Unity 5.3.4f1. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I didn't notice that. I've edited the question.

Comment: Can you please show what is in updateCurrentPosition ?

Comment: I've added the code you asked for, but as I said, it works flawlessy without that specific line of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this on an empty `GameObject` in the scene:

```
public class TestColourAndPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);   
            cube.transform.position = new Vector3(i * 2.0f, 0, 0);
            cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color =  new Color(Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f),Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f),Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f));
        }
    }

    void Update ()
    {
    }
}
```

...No problem with generating random material colours or simple `GameObject` positioning.

So I suspect your problem comes before that, and is corrupting some values leading to the crash.

I suggest you use the above and work slowly and steadily back toward what you want. And don't call `updateCurrentPosition()` (in `Update()` or `LateUpdate()`) until you can position the objects statically / once off, without experiencing *any* problems. And switch in your 3D model only once all else is working, in case there is a model problem - unlikely, but possible.

**Morals of the story** When stumped, revert to a minimal test case and make your way from there. Always test incrementally as you code - so you know the *exact* change where things begin to fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tryed your script and I've figured out that the problem is caused by me instantiating the model. In fact it works fine with both your example and in mine using the PrimitiveType.Cube instead of my model. But I have still no clue on what's happening...

Comment: @Aurasphere Hmm... I half suspected that. Sometimes I have seen meshes give strange problems in Unity if they are not built correctly. If you can recreate the model in e.g. Blender, maybe try doing that. Or import it into your 3D editing tool and see if there are any obvious problems...?

Comment: Yeah the model was the problem and I was able to fix that, although the color is still not changing. It works fine if I use primitive types though...

Comment: @Aurasphere Do you know what colours you want to use at runtime? If so, and if they are few, set up several materials in the Editor, set their colours, and just use them by name at runtime, rather than setting `.color` directly..

Comment: I've tried it but it's still not working. If I click on the instantiated object in the hierarchy I see the material with the correct color I associated at runtime (so the program part is working) but the game view shows the prefab color. If I change the prefab color, the game view changes, but programmatically I've no way to change it. I have this exactly problem with the old solution. The only thing I could think of is that I'm missing a call to a method that refresh the renderer... Could it be? Thank you.